# How to load specific script and css for a specific View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Suppose I have a view called `Login.cshtml`, which I need to load these:

```
<link href="~/css/particle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/js/particle-js/particles.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/particle-js/app.js"></script>
```

In my application I have also `_Layout.cshtml` which contains the basic script to load for each, page. How can I load the script and css above in the when the user access to `Login.cshtml` view, as happen in `_Layout.cshtml`?

What I learned is the existence of `@section`, but I don't if is the best practive to do this, someone could suggest me how to do it properly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section seems to be the appropriate solution for this use case.

So you will use the `RenderSection` method in your layout cshtml file. For example, if you want to include some static resources inside the `head` section of the document, you will create a new section in the head element of your layout

```
<head>
      @RenderSection("PageCss",required:false)
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       @RenderBody()
       @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </div>
</body>
```

and in your view(`Login.cshtml`), you will add the static resources through this specific section.

```
@section PageCss
{
   <link href="~/css/particle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="~/js/particle-js/particles.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/js/particle-js/app.js"></script>    
}
@section PageCss
{
   <script src="~/js/anotherSciptWhichDoesNotBlockRendering.js"></script>
}
```

When razor executes the code, it will render the correct html.

You may create more than one section and use it as needed.

Consider using the `async` and `defer` attributes on script tag as appropriate to prevent render blocking script download/execution behavior.

Comment: +1, although it is best practice to load javascript at the bottom of the page, so it would probably be better to include two sections: 1 at the top for CSS and 1 at the bottom for JS.